# npm audit not recognising issues resolved at lower level

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having an issue with resolving a warning highlighted by npm audit. I followed the path to the dependent package which had the issue and ran the suggested fix command to update the dependency package that was causing the issue.

The path looks like this: npm/node_modules/npm-profile/node_modules/make-fetch-happen

Now when I run npm audit in the make-fetch-happen folder there are no errors, and the same happens with npm-profile and npm. But when I go back up one level to the package containing npm the audit still highlights the original issue as though it hasn't been resolved.

I am new to using npm so I'm not sure how the file structure works or what effect it has running commands like this at different levels of the file structure.

Is there a command I can run to make the higher level package acknowledge the fix that was run at the lower level?

Comment: you need to add more context to that (error message + dir structure + edit you done) but just purely judging from your post, I would say that it _could_ be a bug.

Comment: There isn't an error message - just a level "high" warning in npm audit that the package should be updated. The fix I implemented was the suggested one - a simple package update.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this bug occurs because the package-lock.json is buggy. If you look for the leveraged library within your package-lock. You should see it by searching for the package name and look to see if there are any with an outdated version number. Chances are there will be. I found being on npm@6.1 deleting both the node_modules and the lock file and npm installing fixed the issue. But sometimes it may not work.